# How to Access Array Value in Underscores Template / CLNDR for Custom Event Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Bit confused about this.

Trying to add a custom class for event days on the CLNDR underscores template.

Here's my underscores template excerpt:

```
<div class="days clearfix">
<% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
<%= console.log(day.events[0]) %>
<div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><span class="day-number"><%= day.day %></span></div>
<% }); %>
</div>
```

From `console.log(day.events[0])` I'm getting back an array with these date values:

[image]

I've tried the obvious, `day.events[0].type` or `<div class="<%= day.classes %> <%= day.events[0].type %>"` to access the type property in this array, but always get this error mesage in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`.

How can I access the type value in the console logged associative array and insert it into my template rendering the word "`incoming`" (the value of type in the array) along with `<%= day.classes %>` in my template?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution I'm sure but I got it working by using a `_.each` with an `if` statement to only bring back the first `type` value:

```
<% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
<div class="<%= day.classes %><% _.each(day.events, function(k, v) { %><% if (v == 0) { %> <%= k.type %><% } %><% }); %>"><span class="day-number"><%= day.day %></span></div>
<% }); %>
```

Seems to be working as intended.. I'm sure there is a better answer though if anyone is inclined to share.  Also still confused as to why I cannot access the value directly using `day.events[0].type` -- that would be the most preferred I assume. An `each` loop seems to be a hackish work-around though.